# How to setup and confirm hardware acceleration in Linux

Tags: linux, kde, chrome, gpu

I'm using Fedora 36, KDE on a Framework laptop with core i7-1185G7.
I use Google meet on Chrome, but it uses too much CPU (about 35%, when CPU is in full speed), warms up the CPU, and could trigger thermal throttling where clock falls to 400Mhz or even 200Mhz for a minute. I've improved that with a cooling pad for the laptop.

The same Google meet works great on my android phone, ipad or M1 Mac. No excessive heat, etc.

From my understanding, my CPU is supposed to have an iGpu that's adequate for things like video compression/decompression.

How can I monitor which processes are using the GPU? How can I set my OS and applications to use the GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are good questions and there are no answers. For Intel GPUs there's a `intel_gpu_top` utility (found in the `intel-gpu-tools`  package) which shows GPU load (without showing individual apps), so you can at least understand whether your system is currently using CPU or GPU, but that's it. For NVIDIA GPUs, there's `nvidia-smi` which shows GPU utilization and apps using it but now how much of GPU each app uses. For AMD there's `radeontop` which again doesn't break GPU usage by app.

There's no way to "configure apps to use your GPU" - they either do it or not. In case of web browsers (Firefox/Chrome), there are certain internal flags which allow to e.g. enable HW video acceleration for video decoding but they are experimental. Check this article for more info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hardware_video_acceleration

Speaking of "Google meet on Chrome" - most likely it only uses your CPU for video encoding/decoding vs. e.g. Chrome under Windows which could use your GPU to do the same while consuming 10 times less power because it's hardware accelerated. You could try enable at least HW video **de**coding acceleration using the provided article. As for HW video **en**coding acceleration I've no clue. I've not seen any Linux applications offering or using it.

Comment: About your last statement : ffmpeg (at least) used to offer the possibility for hardware encoding thanks to the NVENC Nvidia proprietary API. (Of course limited to the codecs the card supports)

Comment: Yeah, I remember that. That's not even enabled by default by most distros - you have to compile your own version of ffmpeg.